# Show $\cosh{[0,\infty)}=[1,\infty)$ and $\sinh{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Show $\cosh{[0,\infty)}=[1,\infty)$ and $\sinh{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}$.

I have shown that both functions are strictly increasing (hyperbolic cosine strictly decreading on the negatives but that should’t matter here?). Also, it is shown that the functions are continuous. From thid, how can I show that they are indeed having the domain and thus range. I sm sure that I have to use the intermediate value theorem but do not know how to formally show this.

Comment: What are you trying to represent using a function of a set. Does it mean applying the function on the set is equivalent to applying the function on each element of that set?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $S\subseteq X$, the notation $f(S)$ is commonly used to indicate $\{y\in Y\,:\, \exists s\in S,\, f(s)=y\}$ (or, in another notation, $\{f(s)\,:\, s\in S\}$). Sometimes you see pop out the notation $f[S]$ instead, though I don't exactly know if the authors who do this use square brackets to represent the image map $f[\bullet]:\mathcal P(X)\to \mathcal P(Y)$, or the preimage map $f^{-1}[\bullet]:\mathcal P(Y)\to \mathcal P(X)$ or with both. Here the parenthesis have been omitted, but the point is that there isn't really an elegant way to use the notation here.

Comment: You can show the sinh one readily by inverting directly. Similarly you can do the same thing for cosh but also using AM-GM inequality to show it has a min which is obtained at a specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y\in[0,\infty)$.

You have $\cosh(0)\leqslant y$ and, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cosh(x)=\infty$, there is some $x_0\in[0,\infty)$ such that $\cosh(x_0)>y$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is some $x\in[0,x_0]$ such that $\cosh(x_1)=y$. The case of $\sinh$ is similar.

Comment: For $\sinh$ - picking a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ yields me some problems for the following step. Hyperbolic sine will diverge for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ to $\pm \infty$ so when you have "$\cosh(0) \leq y$ that step is causing me trouble.

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sinh(x)=-\infty$, there is some $x_0$ such that $\sinh(x_0)<y$. And, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sinh(x)=\infty$, there is some $x_1$ such that $\sinh(x_1)>y$. And now you can apply the intermediate value theorem to the interval $[x_0,x_1]$.

Comment: but wouldn't I have to pick a $x_1$ in the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ by the IVT (I know that does not make sense).

Comment: You pick $x_2\in[x_0,x_1]$ such that $f(x_2)=y$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both are continuous.

- $\cosh$ is strictly increasing and s.t. $\cosh(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty }\cosh(x)=+\infty $. Therefore, Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT) allows you to conclude.
- Same with $\sinh$, it's strictly increasing and s.t. $\lim_{x\to -\infty }\sinh(x)=-\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to \infty }\sinh(x)=+\infty $. So, IVT allows you to conclude.

Comment: Why does ivt allow me to conclude this. That is my confusion.

Comment: Take $y\in [1,\infty )$. Since $\lim_{x\to \infty }\cosh(x)=+\infty $, there is $M>0$ s.t. $\cosh(u)>y$ for all $u\geq M$. In particular, $y\in \cosh[0,M]$, and thus, there is $x\in [0,M]$ s.t. $y=\cosh(x)$. Therefore, $[1,\infty )\subset \cosh[0,\infty )$. The converse inclusion is obvious.

Comment: But Cosh is not strictly increasing.

Comment: Of course it is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty )$. @mathstudent23